# Symfony 2 Security: keeps reloading data from user provider?

Tags: php, symfony

When a user is already logged in, the Security component keeps reloading data from the user provider on every reqyest. Is there a way to avoid this? When your user provider is not in a local database, for example, in a webservice, this can dramatically slow down the system.

On every request i get this:

```
[2012-08-15 20:07:30] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2012-08-15 20:07:30] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
```

Comment: Users are refreshed by calling UserProvider::refreshUser.  So you could extend the system provider and change refreshUser to not do anything or maybe add some timing logic.  That is what I do.  Kind of curious to see if there is better way.

Comment: refreshUser() is called on every request? Also, what do you do? You just return null on it?

Comment: Yes and yes. Of course it is then up to you to reload the user if their information changes.

Comment: If i return null, the authentication stops working.

Comment: can show your refreshUser method? if your refreshUser only wraps the loaduserByName you need some cache for speed your method

Answer (score 6):

You can decide wether or not to refresh your user for each request depending on your needs by overriding the `refreshUser` method of the `UserProviderInterface` implementation you rely on from a given security context.

Please refer to the following API documentation:

[UserProviderInterface.html#method_refreshUser](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.html#method_refreshUser)

> It is up to the implementation to decide if the user data should be
>   totally reloaded (e.g. from the database), or if the UserInterface
>   object can just be merged into some internal array of users / identity
>   map.

Comment: Wouldn't that break security?

Comment: It would depend on how frequently your users data are supposed to be updated (and as a result refreshed) while they're logged in.

Comment: http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.html#method_refreshUser